# SailsJs res.render vs res.view

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I'm trying to use SailsJs to make a simple authentication web app with PassportJs + EJS template engine.

This is my code in the AuthenController.coffee

```
processSignin: (req, res) ->
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) ->
    if err or not user
      return res.view('auth/signin', message:'failed')
    req.logIn user, (err) ->
      return res.view('auth/signin', message:'failed') if err
      res.redirect '/'
  ) req, res
  return
```

If I use: `res.render('/auth/login', { message:'err' })`

the browser **only** return HTML code of the login.ejs

If I use: `res.view('/auth/login', { message:'err' })` 
then it return login.ejs code **wrapped in the layout.ejs's <%-body%>**

Any explanation for this different? Is it a new feature of Sails or built-in of Express? Where I can find documents about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`res.render` is an [expressJS method](http://expressjs.com/api.html), while `res.view` is a [SailsJs method](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/views). The latter wraps the requested view in the default layout unless a different layout is requested. So you'll have to decide whether you want just the compiled template you're requesting (`res.render`) or the more complete view (`res.view`).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Now it's clear for me :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'wraps the requested view in the default layout' ? If I write 'res.view('myTemplate',obj);', what will default view have to do with it ?